# Appending div's in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to do the following:

I have li's inside one ul . Suppose I have 15 li's and I want to append a div after the 4th li and 12th li. 
How can I do that in angular? 
Here's what my code looks like:

```
<ul class="story">
    <li id="pos+{{$index}}" ng-repeat= "item in stories" ng-if="$index!==5 && $index!==13" >
    <div id="xyz">.... </div>
    <div id = "pqr"> ... </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The li's are placed as follows: Initially only  7 li's are visible. If more are to be seen "show more" is hit and more 7 li's will be visible.

```
li1 li2
li3 li4  **li5**
li6  li7 

Show more 

li8 li9 li10

li11 li12 **li13**

li14 li15
```

In place of li5 and li13 I want to append two separate div's with different id's. Is there any easy way to do it?

```
<div id="first"> </div>  This will be in li5 position ie next to li4
<div id="second"> </div>  This will be in li13 position ie next to li12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `ng-repeat-start` combined with `ng-repeat-end` along with a conditional `ng-if` to check index.

Will use `limitTo` filter to set how many to show and start point. For demo it just toggles the start at 0 or 7...leave it to you to add better logic

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat-start="item in items | limitTo:7:start">{{item.item}}</li>
<li ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index==3" ng-click="toggleStart()">Change Start</li>
```

JS

```
 $scope.start =0;

 $scope.toggleStart = function(){
     $scope.start = $scope.start === 0 ? 7 :0;
 }
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9chyTaONwRwkO6ek7yQF?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: hey @charlietfl I have show more after 7 li's & not after 4 li's . The show more functionality works. All I'm concerned about is placing the div with id first , next to 3rd li & placing div with id second next to 12th li.

Comment: OK...I actually did just that in my initial answer....then thought you wanted the full feature set. Can you see the edit history on my answwer? Might need more reputaion to do that

Comment: ie as the li's are getting populated, I want a way in which I can dynamically append first div in 5th li position & second div in 13th li position.

Comment: anyway...can change the `ng-if` to `ng-if="$index==3 || $index==11"`

Comment: I guess this is what you sent me earlier http://plnkr.co/edit/9chyTaONwRwkO6ek7yQF?p=preview

Comment: yeah...you probably can't see the revisions inside this answer...check demo again

Comment: but in your previous demo the items are one below the other . So the first special item is seen next to li4 but after show more is hit, the special item which should be seen next to  li12 is seen below the previous special item.

Comment: It's all rough... I am mereley showing you how...surely you can make adjustments? I'm not totally sure what you need

Comment: I want li5 and li13 to be placed similar to the picture above in my question

Comment: and that's exactly what the second simple version does. You said you had the rest working. Look at bottom version...after 4 and after 12

Comment: ummm yeah checked it but I'm trying to append two different div's with different id's. Bit confused ..

Comment: so if it's index 3 do one thing, if it's index 11 do another. A directive could be put in there also. In angular ID's are rarely needed or used

Comment: yeah but how can I have two ng-repeat-end?? ng-repeat-end can be applied only once per ng-repeat-start.  Correct ?

Comment: You don't you adjust at that element...look at demo now. I strongly suggest you study some angular tutorials. The framework is very very flexible. A directive on that element would be ideal but using the core directives you can do an aweful lot.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would be to preprocess your data within the controller, map it to an array that has all your states covered:

```
var stories = [
    {story: storyData, visible: true, div: false},
    {story: storyData, visible: true, div: false},
    {story: storyData, visible: true, div: false},
    {story: storyData, visible: true, div: false},
    {story: storyData, visible: true, div: true},
    ...
];

$scope.stories = stories;
```

Then in the view you can easily iterate using `entry in stories`, and use triggers like `ng-show="entry.div"` to alternate between div vs. non-div, `ng-show="entry.visible"` to alternate between visible-immediately vs. when show-more is clicked.

You can have a button trigger `$scope.showMore()`, which could process this data to switch state of visible from false to true on the next `n` records, starting at the first record that is hidden.